# Apache modsecurity: limit requests per resource per second

Tags: apache, mod-security2

I'm trying to configure modsecurity for Apache to limit the number of requests to the same resource per unit of time: 10 hits per second per resource, no matter which ip address does the request. It is desirable do not block extra calls but redirect to a given page.

I included module and placed next code in httpd.conf:

```
<LocationMatch "(.*)\.dimg(.*)">
  SecDebugLogLevel 9
  SecAction phase:2,initcol:resource=%{REQUEST_URI},pass,nolog,id:132
  SecRule RESOURCE:COUNT "@gt 10" "phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:503,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1,nolog,id:102"
  SecAction "phase:2,setvar:resource.count=+1,pass,nolog,id:103"
  SecAction "phase:5,deprecatevar:resource.count=10/1,pass,nolog,id:104"
  Header always set Retry-After "10" env=RATELIMITED
  ErrorDocument 503 "Service Unavailable"
```

Then I run stress test to simulate high load.
But extra requests are not blocked. 
From logs:
Recorded original collection variable: resource.count = "0"

As a result SecRule RESOURCE:COUNT "@gt 10" returns false for any request.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Hello! did you get this working? I need to limit the request per second for a particular URI.